# Sphinx include only classes, functions which contain docstring

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx

I have multiple classes in a python file (sqlalchemy classes to be precise). I am trying to document some classes with sphinx package.

I put some docstrings under some classes but in the end all classes are listed, with and without docstring.

I am using **autodoc**:

```
Contents:

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 3

.. automodule:: blog.models
   :members:
```

The only way I can specify which classes I want to be included is like this:

```
.. automodule:: blog.models
   :members: SomeClass, SomeClass2, .., SomeClass1001
```

Is there a way to add only classes, functions, which are with docstring?

Comment: Please edit your question to include any errors. This is not enough information to help.

Comment: Generally, you'd need to specify [:undocumented:](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html?highlight=undocumented#directive-option-automodule-undoc-members) on your autodoc directive to see undocumented objects, as it defaults to false.  By the description of the behaviour you're seeing though, it seems to be set to be on by default.  Have you checked whether it's been turned on in your conf.py?  Otherwise, you'll likely get better help if you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.